# pandas dataframe convert to xyz data to use for pyecharts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tring to use pyecharts to draw a 3D-BARS diagram, the data structure like as follows came from a csv file.

```
Date        School1 School2 School3
2021/3/1    853     195     316 
2021/3/2    165     257     461 
2021/3/3    469     314     167 
2021/3/4    857     532     495 
2021/3/5    326     139     595 
2021/3/6    802     616     439 
2021/3/7    768     962     416 
2021/3/8    911     241     82 
2021/3/9    960     965     229
```

Pyecharts Bar3D plot datas as X, Y, Z axis way, like following order:

```
x0,y0,z0(value)
x0,y1,z1
x0,y2,z2
...
x1,y0,zn
```

So is there any simple way to convert the above dataframe data into this 'xyz' data?

Comment: The data is compatible with only 2D graphs.

Comment: I want to  using school1's datas to display in front of the Bar3D plot(that is, all y is 0, x value is the 'Date' of the dataframe, z value is the value of the corresponding column), school2 is displayed behind school1, school3 is third. If I can rearrange the data, I think it would be work, but I don't know how to do it fast way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a piece of code to convert the data that from dataframe into data sequence which required by pyecharts Bar3D. Although it is a bit troublesome and it's a semi-finished but it can work now. I am very bigenner of python, so the codes is ugly, but I will still post them here.

For the X-axis, I haven't replace it with the date, but this is not too important to me. My main goal is to make another large amount of data to plot graphs in this style. That's is enough for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(r"g:\s1.txt")

S1 = data['School1']
S2 = data['School2']
S3 = data['School3']

Lists1 = []
Lists2 = []
Lists3 = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    s1d = int(S1[i])
    s2d = int(S2[i])
    s3d = int(S3[i])
    Lists1.append([i,0,s1d])
    Lists2.append([i,1,s2d])
    Lists3.append([i,2,s3d])
Listxyz = Lists1 + Lists2 + Lists3
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [bar3d()](https://pyecharts.readthedocs.io/projects/pyecharts-en/en/stable/en-us/documentation.html#bar3d), `data` is represented by a two-dimension array. For `school1`, I think you can do something like

```py
df['y'] = 0

data = df[['Date', 'y', 'School1']].values.tolist()
```

```
print(data)

[['2021/3/1', 0, 853], ['2021/3/2', 0, 165], ['2021/3/3', 0, 469], ['2021/3/4', 0, 857], ['2021/3/5', 0, 326], ['2021/3/6', 0, 802], ['2021/3/7', 0, 768], ['2021/3/8', 0, 911], ['2021/3/9', 0, 960]]
```

If you don't want to edit your original dataframe

```py
df_ = pd.concat([df['Date'], pd.Series([0]*len(df)), df['School1']], axis=1)

data = df_.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for  your advice, Just now I wrote a piece of code to convert data shape to adapt Bar3D of pyecharts, problem resovled, but your code still useful, I will try to use them to convert x-axis to Date format.

Comment: @SunJar Just use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` to convert x-axis to Date format.

Comment: HI,Ynjxsjmh Thank you very much, I will try it late.